# How to Create a Power BI Embedded Resource

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to create a Power BI Embedded resource from azure. I followed all the steps noted in section 1 of the following link [Power BI Embedded](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding-content/#step-1-setup-your-embedded-analytics-development-environment) namely, creating a user in Active Directory, creating a Power BI Pro account with this usage, An application on Azure Active Directory.

Still, I still have the same page that appears.

Does anyone have any idea what that is?

Thanks

[Azure Power BI Embedded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q277k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service `Power BI Embedded` is deprecated, and if you havend used it before you will no longer be able to create that service in Azure. This happend roughly two weeks ago

The message on Azure is supposed to be interpreted as

> You can no longer create this service, instead use the following guide
>   to embed Power BI and do **not** return to this page after

So, you have completed step 1. Now you should move to step 2, Embed Content. Creating a `Power BI Embedded` service in Azure is no longer a step in how to embed Power BI.

If you ask me, a good start for step 2 is https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples where you should start with the `App Owns Data samples`.